Connecting Node.js to GCP
I was trying to connect my Google Cloud Platform (GCP) project to my Next.js application by creating a storage instance as follows:
    const storage = new Storage({
      projectId: process.env.GCP_PROJECT_ID,
      scopes: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
      credentials: {
        client_email: process.env.GCP_CLIENT_EMAIL,
        private_key: process.env.GCP_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, "\n"),
      },
    });

However, I encountered the following error:
⨯ Error: error:1E08010C:DECODER routines::unsupported
    at Sign.sign (node:internal/crypto/sig:128:29)
    at NodeCrypto.sign (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/crypto/node/crypto.js:35:23)
    at GoogleAuth.sign (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:780:39)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async sign (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/esm/src/signer.js:203:35) {
  name: 'SigningError'
}

It should have been connected.
